# Getting this message - Warning: Error in as.tbl: could not find function "as.tbl" while publishing my shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

When I run my shiny app locally, it runs fine but when I see this in the log:

```
2018-10-23T00:54:15.496879+00:00 shinyapps[529396]: Loading required package: data.table
2018-10-23T00:54:21.417674+00:00 shinyapps[529396]: Warning: Error in as.tbl: could not find function "as.tbl"
```

This is the code

> ```
> combined <-
>   merge(loans, banks[, c("Year", "Agency", "ID", "Name")],
>         by = c("Year", "Agency", "ID")) %>%
>   mutate(Loan_Bucket = cut(Loan_Amount_000,       #appending a Loan_Bucket column to the dataframe
>                            breaks = c(0, 50, 350, 2000, 5000, 15000, 40000, 100000),
>                            labels = 1:7),
>          right = FALSE
>   ) %>% as.tbl                                    #tbl prevents printing the whole dataframe by mistake
> ```

I loaded the dplyr using require(dplyr) but still this is occurring. Any ideas?

Comment: could you share your repo for reproducibility?

Comment: Hi, uploaded it here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12IiL2TQw5gU4hqHrxeEvjTy-HG1N6pvd?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server.r, you have

```
options(warn = -1)
packages = c("scales", "readr", "plotly", "editrules", "stringr", "jsonlite",
         "devtools", "tidyr", "data.table", "rjson", "scales", "dplyr", 
"gridExtra", "shiny", "ggplot2")
x = sapply(packages, function(x) if (!require(x, character.only = T)) 
install.packages(x))
rm(x, packages)
```

to install required packages, but after they are installed, these packages are not loaded.

try this:

```
x = sapply(packages, function(x) {
         if (!require(x, character.only = T)) install.packages(x)
         require(x)
})
```

p.s: I would suggest sharing your repo on GitHub so others don't have to download to view the code.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. One of the files exceeds github's limit of 100MB. Thanks for the answer. I tried it and it worked after I used require(dplyr) in the ui.r too. I thought that loading packages in just server.r would be enough! I guess since the my function which reads the data is in ui.r, hence it is being parsed first.